# New trend of seat stay for road bike?

Tags: road-bike, frames

I have seen quiet a few road bike with a Z-shape seat stay until now, e.g. specialized Roubaix

Does it serve any purpose? What's the advantage of this design in comparison to a straight-bar seat stay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They add a bit of suspension to the bike

http://www.specialized.com/us/en/technology/smoother-is-faster

> HOW IT’S DONE From It’s CG-R seatpost to the Zertz viscoelastic
>   dampers in the fork and seatstays, the Roubaix is designed to filter
>   both high frequency vibrations and big hits from the road— so your
>   body doesn’t have to.
>
> ZERTZ The Zertz vibration dampers are designed to take the edge off of
>   high the frequency imperfections that every road rider rider knows
>   well. From chip sealed roads, to cracks and everything in between,
>   Zertz take the edge off of even the worst road surface.